# Clion editor won't recognize standard c++ library

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I am very new to c++ and especially Clion so I may be missing something obvious, but I cannot seem to find a solution to this problem.

When I create a new "Hello World" c++ project it will build and run, but the editor will show problems. It highlights `#include <iostream>` in red and says that it cannot find the library.

This error appears when I change the default toolchain from Visual Studio to a remote host which is my university's Unix server. It seems to connect with the server and compile the project just fine using g++, but the editor seems to have problems with the standard library.

I haven't ever used CMake before, but it seems like altering my CMakeLists.txt file doesn't affect the errors shown in the editor. I followed a tutorial to set up the remote server configuration and it said to add the line:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

to the CMakeLists.txt file. This doesn't seem to have any effect on the errors.

[editor errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQ7Cm.png)

[toolchains config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajSZL.png)

Comment: Avoid hardcoding compiler options, if CMake provides an alternative. In this case there is one that works independent of the compiler: `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11) set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)`. I don't assume this fixes the issue though. Since the screenshot shows a working compilation this may just be an issue with the ide finding the includes.